# CSS branding on Lightning Bolt Solution

Tags: napili, lightning-community, lightning-bolt

When we export a lightning community design (based on Napili) as Lightning Bolt Solution, CSS brandings are not included in the solution.

Is this a bug?

If not, can you point me to documentation where it specifically says CSS branding is not included?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a bug, this is not included and mentioned in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?siteLang=en_us&id=community_builder_export_considerations.htm&language=en_us&type=0)

> The following items are not included when you export a template. After
> you import the template and use it create a community in the
> destination org, you must manually reconfigure these items.
>
> 1. Most Administration settings (except for the settings already
>    listed).
> 2. Community Builder settings, including head markup and the Google
>    Tracking ID.
> 3. Custom theme layouts that aren’t in use. Only theme layouts that are
>    selected in Settings | Theme are included.
> 4. Custom styles in the CSS editor.
> 5. Localized content for multilingual communities.
> 6. Non-default page variations; only default page variations are
>    included. If a page doesn’t have a default variation—for example, a
>    page with two variations that are both set to audience-based
>    visibility—the page is excluded entirely.

As you can see **Custom styles in the CSS editor** are not included